# Selenium error - it does not type my name

Tags: python, selenium, webex

This is my first time using python and I have a few problems. I want to automate webex(auto join meetings) and but i cant get passed this page:https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuaLI.png (it does not type my name) and I get this error:https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPeon.png

**Here are the problems i have:**

Error Code

Does not Type in the box I tell it too

**This is what i have written so far:**

```html
import pytest
import time
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service


service = Service(r"chromedriver.exe")
service.start()
driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url)
driver.get('https://meetingsemea39.webex.com/meet/pr1812997966');
driver.find_element(By.ID, "push_download_join_by_browser").click()
time.sleep (6)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".style-name-input-19PlX > .style-input-2nuAk").click()
time.sleep (3)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".style-name-input-19PlX > .style-input-2nuAk").send_keys("Thanashs Ntouvlis")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "guest_next-btn").click()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".style-audio-case-3xwDo").click()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "interstitial_join_btn").click()
```

I am not able to find how to give you the page source code but this is the url(https://meetingsemea39.webex.com/meet/pr1812997966). Just press **Join from your browser** and you will be on the same page i was.

> You are trying to find element by CSS_SELECTOR, but style-input-2nuAk is a class, not a CSS element.
> To find elements by their class name:
> driver.find_element_by_class_name("class_name")

It still does not type in the box

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find element by CSS_SELECTOR, but `style-input-2nuAk` is a class, not a CSS element.

To find elements by their class name:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("class_name")
```